# List of TimeSpan calculated by results from other list

Tags: c#, .net, list, timespan

I'm trying to create a list based on another list. The list looks like -
`{T1, T1, T2, T2, T3, T3}` however the integer is subject to change based on user inputs. I am trying to assign a `TimeSpan` value on a new list based on the index of the old list, and the integers will vary the result. For example, if the start time is given as 11:00, and the time gap given by the user is 5 (minutes), the new list should look like - `{11:00, 11:00, 11:05, 11:05, 11:10; 11:10}`

Here is my current function:

```
public List<string> TimeGet(List<string> heatList, TimeSpan startTimeSpan, TimeSpan timeGap)
{
    List<string> timeList = new List<string>();
    string timeToAddString;
    for (int i = 0; i < heatList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (heatList[i].Contains("1"))
        {
            TimeSpan timeToAdd = startTimeSpan;
            timeToAddString = Convert.ToString(timeToAdd);
            timeList.Add(timeToAddString);
        }
        else
        {
            string resultString = Regex.Match(heatList[i], @"\d+").Value;
            int resultInt = Int32.Parse(resultString);
            timeGap = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeGap.Minutes * resultInt);
            TimeSpan timeToAdd = startTimeSpan + timeGap;
            timeToAddString = Convert.ToString(timeToAdd);
            timeList.Add(timeToAddString);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the new list to correspond to the values on heatlist depending on the integer based in each string on the list, and produce a timespan or time of day to correspond with it on a new list.

Comment: It is a mistake to have `TimeGet` deal with timespan parsing and formatting. Move that out. Pass in TimeSpans and return TimeSpans. Have this function only deal with TimeSpans. All that formatting logic obscures the real logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can be made much simpler, assuming every element in heatList follows that `T\d+` pattern.

```
public IEnumerable<string> TimeGet(List<string> heatList, TimeSpan startTimeSpan, TimeSpan timeGap)
{
    foreach (var element in heatList)
    {
        var input = element.Substring(1); // Takes everything from index 1 = the first digit in the string
        int multiplier = Int32.Parse(input) - 1;
        var additionalTime = new TimeSpan(0, (int)(timeGap.Minutes * multiplier), 0);
        yield return (startTimeSpan + additionalTime).ToString();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
string[] sBaseList = { "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T4", "T6" };
var sList = sBaseList.ToList();
TimeSpan startSpan = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
TimeSpan gapSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
var result = TimeGet(sList, startSpan, gapSpan);
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result: 11:00:00, 11:00:00, 11:05:00, 11:05:00, 11:15:00, 11:25:00.

Comment: perfect, i used this and then read it into a list to produce the result I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton By "read it into a list" you mean you called `.ToList()` on the result variable, right? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ

```
return heatList
    .Select(t => TimeSpan.FromTicks(
                     (Int32.Parse(t.Substring(1))-1) * timeGap.Ticks
                 )
                 + startTimeSpan).ToString("hh:mm")
    .ToList();
```

Explanation:
`.Select(t => ...)` enumerates the strings from the heatList assigning each temperature to `t`.
`t.Substring(1)` skips the "T" in "T123".
`Int32.Parse(t.Substring(1)) - 1` creates the number range 0, 1, 2 ...
`* timeGap.Ticks` gives the offset for a given temperature in ticks.
`TimeSpan.FromTicks(...) + startTimeSpan)` yields the resulting time by adding timespans.
`.ToString("hh:mm")` converts the resulting timespan into a string.
`.ToList();` creates a new list.

Ticks is the unit `TimeSpan` uses to store time spans internally.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> inputdata = new List<string> ();
            List<TimeSpan> outputdata = new List<TimeSpan> ();

            string input = null;
            while ((input = Console.ReadLine ()) != string.Empty) {
                inputdata.Add (input);
                TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan (11, 0, 0) + new TimeSpan (0, Convert.ToInt32 (Regex.Match (input, "\\d+").ToString ()), 0);
                outputdata.Add (t);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < inputdata.Count; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Inputdata: {0}, Outputdata: {1}", inputdata [i], outputdata [i].ToString ());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with simple linq statement

```
public static List<string> TimeGet(List<string> heatList, TimeSpan startTimeSpan, TimeSpan timeGap)
{
    return heatList
        .Select(x =>
            startTimeSpan.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeGap.Minutes*(int.Parse(x.Substring(1)) - 1)))
                .ToString(@"hh\:mm")).ToList();
}
```

this will select an item from `heatList` one by one, parse the number in it and subtract 1 from it (so `T1` result is `0` and `T2` in `1` and ...), now add `timeGap` times the resulted number to `startTimeSpan` and format it in `hh:mm` format.